# Python - Ubuntu Server

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am wanting to write my first Python script for my Ubuntu VPS and I was wondering the best way to go about doing it.  This script will send me a message every 30 minutes through my gmail account.

Originally, in my head I envisioned a Python script that would just always be running and then would email me once every 30 minutes, like a daemon I guess.  Can you run a Python script like a daemon?

Now that I think about it more though, it may be better to just have a python script that is designed to be executed by crontab.

Which approach do you think is best?  I realize sending an email every 30 min is an almost useless task but it is something I can build on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach is to write your python script to use `smtplib`.

```
def sendEmail(*args):
   #send email
```

[Here](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-through-gmail-with-python/) is a simple tutorial for using smtplib

Then have `cron` or bash script to evoke this script every 30 minutes.
[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) is a simple tutorial on cron

Personally I would just use smtplib + bash script.
and the bash script would look something like:

```
while true
do
 python sendmail.py
 sleep 1800
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the links!  That helps a lot!  Question though, why invoke it every 30 seconds?  Why not just every 30 minutes as the interval?

Comment: I saw your original question as 30 seconds. my mistake

Comment: Oh thanks!  I was so confused, thinking there was some method to the 30 seconds that I didn't understand. :)